# Glyph fonts after rebooting

Tags: arch-linux, fonts

Everything was fine until I casually rebooted my computer. Now in some cases I have a unreadable glyph font that replaced the font in some places : emacs, the code sections on github. How do I proceed to fix that ? Also how do I remove all the glyph fonts it's so useless ?

Apparently `monospace` was turned into a glyph font

Comment: Both cases (emacs, and code) use a monospace font. Your font file might be damaged. You may have accidently renamed the file. The font cache might be damaged. (try running `fc-cache` from a terminal window - might have to use `sudo` - add `--version` to get more verbose information)